# the "vite" plugin does not reload the page automatically

Tags: laravel, vite

I am using laravel 10.33 and installed the plugin "vite".

My Vite config is this one

```
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

As you can see, I have added the option "refresh:true".

My server is started with **php artisan serve**.
And I start vite with **npm run dev**.

When I edit a page in my project, I expect my browser to automatically reload. Which he doesn't do.

However in the console, I can clearly see that 'vite' has detected a modification since I see this:

[image]

What would I have forgotten to do ?

Answer (score 0):

in fact everything works correctly!

As soon as I created my first page with the @vite directive, the mechanics fell into place and the site is refreshed when a modification is made.